# Images does not load properly on phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am having trouble with `image.onload`.
What I am doing is take a list of paths and want to convert them into Base64

```
var img = new Image();
img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
img.onload = function() {
    console.log("image done loading");
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
        width = img.width,
        height = img.height;
    if (width > height) {
        if (width > maxSize) {
            height *= maxSize / width;
            width = maxSize;
        }
    } else {
        if (height > maxSize) {
            width *= maxSize / height;
            height = maxSize;
        }
    }
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg", 0.8);
    callback(imageObj, dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, ""));
};
img.src = URL;
```

Now this is working fine on my computer, but on my phone Galaxy2 (Android 4.1) it only succeed to upload something like 10 photos and then it stop.
I also checked it on Android 4.4, working as excepted.

I added the images to the HTML to see if the images are really loading,
and only half of the images were load properly.
It's look like the onload event stop firing.

Any suggestions?

Comment: When there is an error onerror-handler should fire. did you give this a try?

Comment: yes, but it doesn't say why the error occurred

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finaly i solve that problem,
I tried to load that way more than 100 images simultaneously.

what hapend is on new phones with more ram the app works because it has enough space to save the images, on the other hand on old phone when the ram ran out error fired because he couldn't load the image

so i changed my code that he will load one image at the same time